# Format-Table forgets some properties, but Format-List shows them all. Why?

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-3.0

Given the below [PowerShell 3](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/06/powershell-3-0-is-now-available-for-download.aspx) script, [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) does not list all properties as columns (it skips `NoRemove`), but [Format-List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx) does, and you can force the properties to be there using [Select-Object](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nexthop/archive/2011/03/21/psformatorselect.aspx).

[Out-GridView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx) behaves the same as `Format-Table` and also skips `NoRemove`

Why is that?

Note: this is from a much less restricted `Where-Object` clause, where it looks like `Format-Table` does inspect more than just the first object in the array to guess the columns.

The example comes from [Channel 9 how-to: Print/List installed ​programs/ap​plications sorted by date](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/how-to-PrintList-installed-programsapplications-sorted-by-date) which forgot to initialize the first `Get-ItemProperty` (`gp`) as an array so you got an error like this:

> `Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey] doesn't
>   contain a method named 'op_Addition'.`

Example code:

```
$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys = (@(Get-Item HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*)) + 
(Get-Item HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*) + 
(Get-Item HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*) | 
  Where-Object { $_.ValueCount -eq 1 }

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys.GetType().FullName
$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys | Get-Member

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues = $nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys | 
  Get-ItemProperty

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues.GetType().FullName
$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues | Get-Member

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
  Format-Table

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
  Format-List

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
  Select-Object SystemComponent, NoRemove, PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSProvider |
  Format-Table
```

I used [GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2wzt390.aspx).[FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) and [Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) to inspect the underlying types.

`$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys` starts with all installed software (user, system x64 and system x86) filtered by registry keys having only 1 value (empirically those are the ones you cannot uninstall).

The first part of the output shows that `$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys` is a `System.Object[]` of type [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) with all the right members. Hence the ability to perform a [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) filter on the [ValueCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.valuecount.aspx) property even though the code-completion does not show that.

`$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys` exposes also a few [PowerShell "Extended Type System" `NoteProperty`](https://www.google.com/search?q=PowerShell%20%22Extended%20Type%20System%22%20NoteProperty) properties including `Property` that contain the registry Name/Value pairs under the key and a bunch of `PS*` coming from the registry provider.

`$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues` is also a `System.Object[]` but now of type 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscustomobject) because of the [Get-ItemProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849851.aspx) which expands the Name/Value pairs in the `Property` of each `$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryKeys` item into properties. For the first item in my output, it adds the [SystemComponent](https://www.google.com/search?q=registry%20SystemComponent) property. For the second item it adds [NoRemove](https://www.google.com/search?q=registry%20NoRemove). And it adds a bunch of `PS*` coming from the registry provider.

`Format-Table` output:

```
SystemComponent PSPath                                                                                                                                    PSParentPath                        
--------------- ------                                                                                                                                    ------------                        
              1 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager             Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registr...
                Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC                            Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registr...
              1 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registr...
                Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC                Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registr...
```

`Format-List` output:

```
SystemComponent : 1
PSPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager
PSParentPath    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName     : Connection Manager
PSProvider      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry

NoRemove     : 1
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName  : WIC
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry

SystemComponent : 1
PSPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager
PSParentPath    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName     : Connection Manager
PSProvider      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry

NoRemove     : 1
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName  : WIC
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

`Select-Object` output:

```
SystemComponent NoRemove PSPath                                                                                                                                    PSParentPath               
--------------- -------- ------                                                                                                                                    ------------               
              1          Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager             Microsoft.PowerShell.Cor...
                1        Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC                            Microsoft.PowerShell.Cor...
              1          Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Connection Manager Microsoft.PowerShell.Cor...
                1        Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC                Microsoft.PowerShell.Cor...
```

**Edit:** my environment

```
PS C:\Users\Developer> Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Version, Caption | Format-List
$PSVersionTable

Version : 6.2.9200
Caption : Microsoft Windows 8 Pro

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
PSVersion                      3.0                                                                                                                                                            
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                            
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                        
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18051                                                                                                                                                
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16628                                                                                                                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}                                                                                                                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

These 2 return the same table:

```
$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
  Format-Table

$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
  Format-Table *
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't specify the property names or '*' for all of them, `Format-Table` will print by default just the first 4 (the default value of `$FormatEnumerationLimit`), not ure why you get only three in the ft output. `Format-List` will show all only when the type of objects doesn't have a format view for `Format-List`.

Comment: I did a `$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
    Format-Table *` which also skips `NoRemove`. Something fishy is going on here.

Comment: And if you add -Force?

Comment: This also fails: `$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
    Format-Table * -Force`

Comment: I can see all properties when piping to fl (without -force) and with ft *.

Comment: What OS and PS version do you run? I've added mine to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

```
$nonUninstallableSoftwareRegistryNameValues |
  Select-Object SystemComponent, NoRemove, PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSProvider |
  Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: That works (it is almost the same as the last entry in my example), but why can't `Format-Table` figure this out by itself? Or maybe phrased differently: what criteria does `Format-Table` to determine which columns to pick?